# How to use different column names in a function in R

Tags: r

My data  are similar to the following data:

```
df<-read.table(text=" degree
100
120
140
150
160",header=TRUE)
```

and I have this simple function

```
df1<-function(x){
mean(df$degree)
}
df1(df)
```

I get the mean. However, sometimes I want to use different names for the column name, say 'point' instead of the 'degree'. Indeed, I do not want to use 'degree' in my codes. Happy to describe should you think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass an argument for column name

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm) mean(dat[[colNm]], na.rm = TRUE)
f1(df, "degree")
#[1] 134

f1(setNames(df, "point"), "point")
#[1] 134
```

Comment: I get "NA" using f1(df, "point"). I am not interested in names(df)[1] <- "point" sorry. I am interested in f1(df, "point"), but I get NA

Comment: @user1946911 it is just to show an example.  If you don't have that column in the dataset, it shouldn't work, right?

Comment: @user1946911 not clear about your use case.  You can  either change the column names with `setNames` or make changes within the function

Comment: Not interested I am sorry... I am only interested to get: f1(df, "point") as I show. If not possible, I understand

Comment: @user1946911 without changing the column name or doing a match with previous name, it is not possible because 'point' have no connection or reference when there are many columns

Comment: @user1946911 If it is based on position, you can always do `mean(dat[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)`, but column names need to match

Comment: if you look at my function, it is not consistent with your function. The first code cannot help as my function is easier

Comment: @user1946911 yes, i looked at your function `function(x) mean(df$degree)` and I couldn't understand why a functioin was created there when `x` is not passed at all.  Instead simply do  `mean(df$degree)`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your specific case when the function itself is somewhat strange to me

Comment: I understand, no worries, let's see  possible  other solutions by other people